# Can't delete dag from airflow UI after deleting from dag_bag

Tags: airflow

I deleted dag from airflow dag_bag and corresponding .pyc file as well. When I try to delete the same dag from airflow UI it is showing this error: 
Dag id MY_DAG_ID is still in DagBag. Remove the DAG file first. 
The airflow version I am using is 1.10.4
Even after restarting airflow I'm not able to delete from UI. I was using 1.10.3 previously, but I never faced this issue. I was able to delete from UI after deleting from dags folder.

When I click on that dag in UI it is showing : 
DAG "MY_DAG_ID" seems to be missing.( this is expected as I deleted dag from folder)

Comment: you can try deleting the entries from the metastore db(postgres/mysql etc..) in all the related tables for clearing the DAG

Answer (score 2):

Try stopping the scheduler and the webserver and then deleting the DAG from the command line:

```sh
airflow delete_dag 'MY_DAG_ID'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues after I upgraded to 1.10.6. Here's what I did:

- Before removing the DAG, make sure no instance is on running, retry status. Then Pause it
- Delete on UI or using the command `airflow delete_dag dag_id`
- Restart the scheduler and webserver
- Try to execute `airflow list_dags` to see if it really got deleted.

If it doesn't work, try to upgrade to the latest version.